# AWS CloudWatch - Monitor CPU Utilization per CPU

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I have an EC2 instance with 8 vCPUs. I would like to see metrics (and later on also alarms) on the cpu utilization per CPU.

The [CPUUtilization](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=85354) metric is a total across all cpus.

Since we are running a few processes that are CPU heavy, I would like to know if there is one CPU that is close to 90% utilization or if there are 6 CPUs that are over 20% utiliztion.
Even the max utilization across all CPUs will be good enough.

Is there a way to know that or must it be a custom metric?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [install the CloudWatch agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-on-first-instance.html) on your EC2 instance and set [`totalcpu`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html#CloudWatch-Agent-Linux-section) to "false" (the default is "true"). This will give you a metric per CPU core.

Comment: how do you get both? aggregate and per cpu?